# How to change the font of text of a legend in nvd3?

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I have a legend whose text I'm trying to make bold. However, I want only that text to be bold which is active, like in the case below, I have 3 circles, one of which is filled in black color. That text is currently active.

However how can i make the even the text bold, so that I could get rid of the circle and just use the text to highlight the label that is active?

[image: legends]

I tried removing the 'circle' node from the `nv-legend`, it removed the circle node but didnt quite work with bold text:

```
var intervalControls = graph.select('.nv-wrap g')
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'nv-intervalWrap');           

var controls = nv.models.legend()
    .height(30)
    .color(['#444', '#444', '#444']);

intervalControls
    .datum(controlsErrorData[interval])
    .attr('transform', 'translate(-270,-50)')
    .call(controls)

$('.nv-intervalWrap')
    .find('g')
    .find('.nv-series')
    .find('.nv-legend-symbol')
    .remove()
```

Any ideas on how this can be achieved???

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
// Keep the in-active controls font normal
.nv-controlsWrap .disabled text {
    font-weight: normal !important;
}

// Make the active link bold
.nv-controlsWrap .nv-series text {
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Hope it helps.